# How can I grant permissions to anonymous users per session to download a file?

Tags: webforms, sessions

Anon users can fill out and submit a form (webform). As soon as submitted, the user will be offered to download a pdf file with his entered form data. How can I manage this? With sessions?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Webform protected downloads](https://drupal.org/project/webform_protected_downloads). It's a module I wrote a while ago to tackle this kind of situation.

Edit: Ah, sorry, just read your question again. The part with the modified pdf content depending on user input is not addressed by my module. Though, as the system uses the private file system you could maybe hook into there. This is not trivial though.

I see another easier option. You create a custom menu callback and use webform hooks or the redirect configuration of the webform to send the user to this url that contains the submission id of the webform (say, `special-pdf-access/SUBMISSION_ID)`. With this information you can load the submission, thus accessing all the data entered by the user, then create a pdf file with this info and display a link to that file.

You have to pay attention to security though, so as not to allow arbitrary users to load pdf files they shouldn't have access to. For this you can use the global $_SESSION variable, to store the submission id after webform has processed the submission, and then check in the custom menu callback if the submission id in the session equals the requested submission as given in the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using the webform module, you will have a difficult time because you will need to write an interface module to the webform module. I have done this and it is not straight forward by any stretch of the imagination.

If you were to instead create your own very simple module with the form you could accomplish this easily on submit. You would just take the form data, store it where you like in a database table and then generate the PDF offering the user a link to download the PDF once generated. You could then delete the temporary PDF from your system so prying people could not access it. Name the file something simple and append a unique id associated generated from the session id so that it cannot be easily guessed.

Comment: "and append a unique id associated generated from the session id" how to get it?

Comment: Use a hash() or crc32() checksum. You could also use any various method for generating a unique name for the file. Also, since you should delete the file after a short amount of time or after the user leaves the page, you shouldn't have to worry about collisions or attacks if you information doesn't include things like social security numbers or something like that. You need to determine how much you care about security with this setup. This method I have outlined is fairly safe but for sure not 100% secure. For that, you would have to do more work.